# How can I get my saved mp4 to exactly match the output of plot.show()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

When I try to save the results of an animation to mp4 using **ffmpeg**, I am getting a jumbled mess.

**plt.show()** shows exactly what I want it to show in the animation. However, when I save it using **ffmpeg**, the result is very different from what **plt.show()** returns. I have tried various arguments for **fps** etc. but nothing has helped.

```
%matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl ## uncomment this if you are running this on a Mac
#mpl.use('TkAgg')         ## and want to use blit=True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 
import csv

people = ('','Jim', 'Dan')
plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))

ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis() 
ax.set_xlabel('Skill')
titleList=['Basketball','Hockey','Baseball']
df=[[0,5,7],[0,4,9],[0,2,6]]
def animate(i):
   # Example data
    while i<3:
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_yticklabels(people)
        ax.set_xlabel(titleList[i])
        performance=df[i]

        title = ax.text(0.5,0.95,str(titleList[i]), bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")

        rects = ax.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center',
                color='blue', ecolor='None')
        return [rect for rect in rects] + [title]


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, frames=3, blit=True
                            ,interval=2000,repeat=False)

plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
ani.save('test.mp4')
plt.show()
```

The result is a very fast video where all the data gets written over (similar to the **plt.show()** results when **blit=False**).

Comment: there's an `fps` option you can pass to `ani.save`

Comment: As mentioned, I have tried various options. It does not seem to help.

Comment: The code is obfuscating the actual ffmpeg command being executed, so I can't tell what type of input your giving ffmpeg (images, video, pipe, etc). Note that for images it will assume a frame rate of 25 unless you tell it otherwise with the `-framerate` input option. The actual ffmpeg command and the resulting log would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean by "obfuscating". Happy to provide whatever is necessary. Does -framerate mean the same as "fps"? I have tried playing around with that, but no luck. This code can be copied to Jupyter Notebook and you can see the result. I on Windows btw, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `blit=True` is only useful for showing the plot. To see the animation that gets saved you need to set `blit=False`.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I tried with ```blit=False``` and the video is still totally jumbled. Are you able to see a proper video when you try this code, by any chance?

Comment: No, the point is your animation seemingly works fine through the use of `blit=True`, while you need to program it in a way such that it will work correctly independent of blitting. In this case that would mean to define `ax.barh` outside the animating function and updating it inside. Searching for something like "matplotlib animate bar plot" or similar should also help.

Comment: I see. I tried reading many answers without much success until I used blitting. I will try to keep looking..... Thanks.